# Android: How to create custom shape keys on keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, key, reshape

I wonder how could is possible to make custom shape key on android keyboard. To create custom keyboard is relatively easy, but what needs to be done to create new buttons. They also need to respond with all events as normal keyboard.

Any ideas where to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an image for each key you want on your custom keyboard, and then, create the xml supporting the design of your keyboard and load it in your application with they [Keyboard](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.html) class.
Do you need more details?
If so, I will prepare one if you want, I've been wanting to have a go at this class for a while.

Comment: Isn't enough just overriding the createKeyFromXml() function of Keyboard class?

Comment: oh yeah, I suppose it is possible, though I never tried it. Didn't understand you properly, I thought you wanted to change the whole keyboard

Comment: You understood right, I just thought this would be easier way. I guess not. Perhaps you should go a little more in details :)

Answer (score 1):

Load  it like this

```
Keyboard mQwertyKeyboard = new LatinKeyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
```

**LatinKeyboard**

```
public class LatinKeyboard extends Keyboard
{

    private Key mEnterKey;
    private Key mSpaceKey;

    private Key mModeChangeKey;

    private Key mLanguageSwitchKey;

    private Key mSavedModeChangeKey;

    private Key mSavedLanguageSwitchKey;

    public LatinKeyboard(Context context, int xmlLayoutResId) {
        super(context, xmlLayoutResId);
    }

    public LatinKeyboard(Context context, int layoutTemplateResId, 
            CharSequence characters, int columns, int horizontalPadding) {
        super(context, layoutTemplateResId, characters, columns, horizontalPadding);
    }

    @Override
    protected Key createKeyFromXml(Resources res, Row parent, int x, int y, 
            XmlResourceParser parser) {
        Key key = new LatinKey(res, parent, x, y, parser);
        if (key.codes[0] == 10) {
            mEnterKey = key;
        } else if (key.codes[0] == ' ') {
            mSpaceKey = key;
        } else if (key.codes[0] == Keyboard.KEYCODE_MODE_CHANGE) {
            mModeChangeKey = key;
            mSavedModeChangeKey = new LatinKey(res, parent, x, y, parser);
        } else if (key.codes[0] == LatinKeyboardView.KEYCODE_LANGUAGE_SWITCH) {
            mLanguageSwitchKey = key;
            mSavedLanguageSwitchKey = new LatinKey(res, parent, x, y, parser);
        }
        return key;
    }


    void setLanguageSwitchKeyVisibility(boolean visible) {
        if (visible) {
            // The language switch key should be visible. Restore the size of the mode change key
            // and language switch key using the saved layout.
            mModeChangeKey.width = mSavedModeChangeKey.width;
            mModeChangeKey.x = mSavedModeChangeKey.x;
            mLanguageSwitchKey.width = mSavedLanguageSwitchKey.width;
            mLanguageSwitchKey.icon = mSavedLanguageSwitchKey.icon;
            mLanguageSwitchKey.iconPreview = mSavedLanguageSwitchKey.iconPreview;
        } else {
            // The language switch key should be hidden. Change the width of the mode change key
            // to fill the space of the language key so that the user will not see any strange gap.
            mModeChangeKey.width = mSavedModeChangeKey.width + mSavedLanguageSwitchKey.width;
            mLanguageSwitchKey.width = 0;
            mLanguageSwitchKey.icon = null;
            mLanguageSwitchKey.iconPreview = null;
        }
    }
    void setImeOptions(Resources res, int options) {
        if (mEnterKey == null) {
            return;
        }

        switch (options&(EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION|EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION)) {
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO:
                mEnterKey.iconPreview = null;
                mEnterKey.icon = null;
                mEnterKey.label = res.getText(R.string.label_go_key);
                break;
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT:
                mEnterKey.iconPreview = null;
                mEnterKey.icon = null;
                mEnterKey.label = res.getText(R.string.label_next_key);
                break;
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH:
                mEnterKey.icon = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.sym_keyboard_search);
                mEnterKey.label = null;
                break;
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND:
                mEnterKey.iconPreview = null;
                mEnterKey.icon = null;
                mEnterKey.label = res.getText(R.string.label_send_key);
                break;
            default:
                mEnterKey.icon = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.sym_keyboard_return);
                mEnterKey.label = null;
                break;
        }
    }

    void setSpaceIcon(final Drawable icon) {
        if (mSpaceKey != null) {
            mSpaceKey.icon = icon;
        }
    }

    static class LatinKey extends Keyboard.Key {

        public LatinKey(Resources res, Keyboard.Row parent, int x, int y,
                XmlResourceParser parser) {
            super(res, parent, x, y, parser);
        }

        /**
         * Overriding this method so that we can reduce the target area for the key that
         * closes the keyboard. 
         */
        @Override
        public boolean isInside(int x, int y) {
            return super.isInside(x, codes[0] == KEYCODE_CANCEL ? y - 10 : y);
        }
    }

}
```

**Static class LatinKey is neccessary because with the help of this you can change state of key in xml if you want.**

**qwerty.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px"
    android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height"
    >

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="113" android:keyLabel="q" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="119" android:keyLabel="w"/>
        <Key android:codes="101" android:keyLabel="e"/>
        <Key android:codes="114" android:keyLabel="r"/>
        <Key android:codes="116" android:keyLabel="t"/>
        <Key android:codes="121" android:keyLabel="y"/>
        <Key android:codes="117" android:keyLabel="u"/>
        <Key android:codes="105" android:keyLabel="i"/>
        <Key android:codes="111" android:keyLabel="o"/>
        <Key android:codes="112" android:keyLabel="p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="97" android:keyLabel="a" android:horizontalGap="5%p" 
                android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="115" android:keyLabel="s"/>
        <Key android:codes="100" android:keyLabel="d"/>
        <Key android:codes="102" android:keyLabel="f"/>
        <Key android:codes="103" android:keyLabel="g"/>
        <Key android:codes="104" android:keyLabel="h"/>
        <Key android:codes="106" android:keyLabel="j"/>
        <Key android:codes="107" android:keyLabel="k"/>
        <Key android:codes="108" android:keyLabel="l" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="-1" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_shift" 
                android:keyWidth="15%p" android:isModifier="true"
                android:isSticky="true" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="122" android:keyLabel="z"/>
        <Key android:codes="120" android:keyLabel="x"/>
        <Key android:codes="99" android:keyLabel="c"/>
        <Key android:codes="118" android:keyLabel="v"/>
        <Key android:codes="98" android:keyLabel="b"/>
        <Key android:codes="110" android:keyLabel="n"/>
        <Key android:codes="109" android:keyLabel="m"/>
        <Key android:codes="-5" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_delete" 
                android:keyWidth="15%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
                android:isRepeatable="true"/>
    </Row>

    <Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
        <Key android:codes="-3" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_done" 
                android:keyWidth="15%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="-2" android:keyLabel="123" android:keyWidth="10%p"/>
        <!--
            android:codes: -101 is not a framework-defined key code but a key code that is
            privately defined in com.example.android.softkeyboard.LatinKeyboardView.
        -->
        <Key android:codes="-101" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_language_switch"
                android:keyWidth="10%p"/>
        <Key android:codes="32" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_space" 
                android:keyWidth="30%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
        <Key android:codes="46,44" android:keyLabel=". ,"
                android:keyWidth="15%p"/>
        <Key android:codes="10" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_return" 
                android:keyWidth="20%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```