# Android keyboard key preview background image

Tags: android, image, background, keyboard, preview

DEVELOPING AN ANDROID KEYBOARD:
how can I change the background image of the key preview?

Comment: Maybe this post will help You: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979926/android-how-to-create-custom-shape-keys-on-keyboard

Comment: Thanks very much, but that post applies to the key background. I want to change the key PREVIEW background.

Answer (score 5):

If you are creating your custom keyboard by extending KeyboardView then we can set a custom key preview layout to our custom KeyboardView using 'android:keyPreviewLayout' attr.

E.g.

```
 <com.example.myApp.MyCustomKeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/my_custom_layout" />
```

where my_custom_layout.xml is your custom preview layout something like

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="80sp"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse"
    android:minWidth="32dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/black"/>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks evr, That's very close to what I wanted. I just changed color to an image & didn't need the values: android:background="@drawable/preview"

Comment: I want to change keyPreviewLayout on LongPress event of My Key is it possible??